# How can I add a string before every match?

Tags: regex, perl

How can I add word `info` as leading everywhere there is word matching `zzzz` with regex?

like `infozzzz`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

$string = " zzzz  mike  zzzz stone zzzz";
$string =~ m/zzzz/;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the substitution operator like so:

```
$string =~ s/(zzzz)/info${1}/g;
```

Or simply:

```
$string =~ s/zzzz/info$&/g;
```

`$variable =~ s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/g;` : Replace `PATTERN` with `REPLACEMENT` in `$variable`.
`(zzzz)` : Match literal string `zzzz`, capture using parenthesis into capture variable `$1`.
`$&` : Capture variable that contains the entire matched `PATTERN`.
`/g` : A regex modifier that tells to match the pattern repeatedly.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Comment: not printing anything `#!/usr/bin/perl 

$string = "zzzz  mike  zzzz stone zzzz";
$string = s/(zzzz)/info${1}/g;

print $string;`

Comment: Or just `s/zzzz/info$&/g`

Comment: @ikegami Is there a slowdown associated with `$&`? I found the docs a bit unclear, especially for modern (>5.20) Perl versions: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Capture-groups

Comment: Before 5.20, `$&` caused every pattern to behave as if it had captures, whether it did or not. That's no longer the case. `$&` doesn't impose any penalty that captures wouldn't. (Independently, `$&` and captures *might* be faster than they used to be thanks to COW. Not sure about this.)

Comment: @ikegami Thank you for the suggestion to use the simpler method with `$&`, and for the explanation about its performance. Updated the answer.